# how to give rank serially

Tags: sql

I have a table like

```
   name          age
   -----------------
   jagga         25 
   lipu          25 
   aswinee       24 
   lisu          23 
   ankita        25 
   jhon          23
```

I want the out put like

```
   name         age     rank
   -------------------------
   ankita       25      1 
   jagga        25      2  
   lipu         25      3 
   aswinee      24      4 
   jhon         23      5  
   lisu         23      6
```

The `name` and `age` must have `order by` clause  but the `rank` would count start from 1.

Comment: What rdbms do you use?

Comment: `select name, age, row_number() over () as rank from your_table order by age desc, name;`

Answer (score 2):

We do not know which dbms you are using, so
for [**MySQL**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45bf7/14)

```
SET @id := 0;
SELECT test.name
,      test.age
,      @id := @id + 1 AS rank
FROM   test
ORDER BY age desc, name;
```

[**MS SQL Server**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45bf7/6)/**[Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45bf7/10)/[Postgresql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/45bf71/3)**:

```
SELECT name
,      age
,      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY age DESC, name) AS rank   
FROM   test
ORDER BY age desc, name
```

Answer (score 0):

just to mention that The ranking function "row_number" must have an ORDER BY clause. and i agree with horsenoname

```
select name,age,row_number() over (order by age desc,name) as rank from mytable order by age desc,name
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see @a_horse_with_no_name's comment.

If your `RDBMS` is `mysql`:

```
select
    t.name,
    t.age,
    @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
from (
    SELECT name, age
    FROM tbl order by name
) as t,
(select @rank := 0) as r
```

Answer (score 0):

By using Analytical Function `Rank`

```
SELECT NAME, AGE, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AGE DESC, NAME) Rank FROM STUDENTS;
```

Answer (score 0):

select `name`,`age`,
`row_number()` over (order by `age` desc) as `rank`
 from `table_name` order by `age` desc,`name`